# Could anyone help? Using a registration form with javascript that is carrying data to a secondary page and the data is not computing

Tags: javascript, html, registration

I have a registration page that uses firstname, email, password and confirm password, for my first name data i have it set up so it should then transfer to a second page and display "Welcome ___", but the data is not showing and is not in the URL (im using query strings). I would like to be able to keep all of my different special effects and have a second page with a welcoming.

display.html:

```
<form action="action.html" method="GET">
<form>
<div>
   <p>
      Full name: <span id="one">..</span>.
      <input  type="text" name="Welcome" id="firstname" placeholder="E.g. David Bowie" />
      <script>
         function inputAction() {
             one.textContent = firstname.value;
         }
         
         firstname.oninput = inputAction;
         
         let Firstnames = [];
         
         const addFirstname = (ev)=>{
             ev.preventDefault();  
             let firstname = {
                 id: Date.now(),
                 firstname: document.getElementById('firstname').value,
             }
             Firstnames.push(firstname);
             document.forms[0].reset(); 
         
         
             console.warn('added' , {Firstnames} );
             let pre = document.querySelector('#msg pre');
             pre.textContent = '\n' + JSON.stringify(Firstnames, '\t', 2);
         
         
             localStorage.setItem('Firstname', JSON.stringify(Firstnames) );
         }
         document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ()=>{
             document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', addFirstname);
         });
      </script>               
</div>
<div>
</p>
<label id="Email">Email</label></br>
<input type="email" placeholder="DavidBowie@gmail.com" id="Email" />
</p>
```

action.html:

```
 <div id='write'>
 <p>Welcome </p>
 </div>

<script>
    let args=new URLSearchParams( location.search );
    if( args.has('Welcome') ){
        document.getElementById('write').querySelector('p').textContent += args.get('Welcome');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Javascript is not java http://javascriptisnotjava.com/

Comment: You seem to have a form nested inside another form.  That doesn't work, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms